# GeoDjango geometry transform method is swapping x with y

Tags: coordinate-system, geodjango

I need to convert a geometry from srid 4326 to srid 3857:

```
myPoint4326 = Point(x=-73,y=40, srid=4326)
myPoint3857 = myPoint4326.transform(3857,clone=True)
print(myPoint4326.wkt)
print(myPoint3857.wkt)
```

The transform method seem to swap my point x with y:

```
POINT (-73 40)
POINT (4452779.631730943 -12123477.91689172)
```

When I draw the "POINT (4452779.631730943 -12123477.91689172)" on https://maththinking.com/gisvisualizer/# , it is not the same location as POINT (-73 40).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/193669/29431

Comment: thanks @KadirŞahbaz I checked the thread and it does not explain my transformed point (myPoint3857) is shown in a different location than my initial point (myPoint4326)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by upgrading Django to 3.2.
https://github.com/django/django/commit/58f1b07e49a98bb391c9e38b91f078ab2c302703